# Only Django request.body contains data (not request.POST)

Tags: python, html, django, forms, request

I am using forms in Django and trying to get the get the data back using `request.POST`, but this returns an empty dictionary for me: `<QueryDict: {}>`. When using `request.body`, however, I get the raw data back. How can I get the data from `request.POST` as well, because I do not want to work with raw data. The console output of the print statements are put in comments next to them.

forms.py

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First name:', max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last name:')
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def blank(request):
    form = NameForm()
    print(f"request.body: {request.body}") # request.body: b'first_name=Adam&last_name=Smith'
    print(f"request.POST: {request.POST}") # request.POST: <QueryDict: {}>

    return render(request, 'blank.html', {'form': form})
```

blank.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you submit your form?

Comment: @NKSM What do you mean?

Comment: by pressing the submit button from the input with type submit

Comment: use `if request.method == "POST": print(f"request.POST: {request.POST}")`

Comment: What do you get if you print `request.method` and `request.content_type`?

Comment: @NKSM, I get the same thing: `<QueryDict: {}>`

Comment: @IainShelvington, request.method: `POST`, request.content_type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @PythonCoder135241 Very strange. Does changing the order so that you print `request.POST` first do anything? Could be something weird where after you read the body it's empty and the POST data can't be populated

Answer (score 0):

#### Retrieve data from django forms

```py
form = NameForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        first_name= form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        last_name= form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
```